# How to make a UIViewController the root of a NavigationController stack?

Tags: ios

I'm currently pushing my main UIViewController from appDelegate with this code:

```
HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];
//self.navigationController.view = homeViewController.view;
[homeViewController release];
```

However, I want it to be the root of the UINavigationController controllers stack, while it is currently possible to move back to another root view controller.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

For example:

```
HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:homeViewController] animated:YES];
[homeViewController release];
```